# Best modern Web Server engine or framework on Java for HTTP requests?

Tags: java, http, webserver

Could you tell me, what is the best Web Server engine for embedding into Java application? I have some logic written on Java and I want this logic to be wrapped into Web Server. Solution must be stable, fast and do not have memory leaks.

Comment: There is no "best" WebServer engine. The choice will always depend on the projects requirements and the engineering skills / experience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd have a look at [jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/). Don't know if it's "the best" but it is embeddable and widely used. If a lot of engineers trust it, it can't be bad.

Comment: I have often embedded Jetty, never had any problems. It's lean, fast and reliable.

Comment: Please tell me, is Jetty 7 stable or not? What version I need to try 6 or 7 ?)))

Comment: @Edward83 - AFAIK, the project moved to eclipse and Version 7 is the first one released under EPGL. It may be easier to start with the [latest stable Jetty 6](http://dist.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-6.1.25/) and update later once your familiar with the system. Using Jetty 7 outside eclipse looks like being a little more complicated (depends on maven)

Answer (score 4):

Best? probably not yet. Fast? yes. Take a look at [Deft](http://deftserver.org)

disclaimer: I'm a deft committer

Answer (score 3):

I've enjoyed using [HttpCore](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/index.html) from [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/):

> HttpCore is a set of low level HTTP transport components that can be used to build custom client and server side HTTP services with a minimal footprint. HttpCore supports two I/O models: blocking I/O model based on the classic Java I/O and non-blocking, event driven I/O model based on Java NIO.

I won't claim that it's "best" or "modern", but it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

> Solution must be stable, fast and do not have memory leaks

1)  Speed, stability and absence of memory leaks are largely a result of what you do (and the mistakes that you don't make) in your webapp.

2)  Certain classes of memory leaks (i.e. involving permgen) are a consequence of hot-loading webapps and retained references to objects created by old classloaders.  These are not really the fault of the webserver, and they certainly cannot be solved at that level.

Answer (score 0):

I have Jetty 7 and haven't had problems our system supports several thousand concurrent in rich media sessions. Here is a tutorial which will get you up and running in minutes.

http://www.techtraits.ca/?p=135